# Using Livewire to populate form input after wire:click

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Thank you for taking the time to read and perhaps reply. I think I may have gotten myself so far down the rabbit hole, I'm overlooking an obvious answer.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a form with numerous text inputs rendered using Laravel Collective. I have a Bootstrap modal which allows a user to input a URL:

```
<div>
    <input wire:model="url" type="text">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" wire:click="scrape">Scrape</button>
</div>
```

Upon submitting the URL, I have a Livewire method which parses specific data from the URL:

```
`public $url;

public function scrape()
    {
      $link = GoutteFacade::request('GET', $request->url);

      //dd($link->filter('title')->text());
    }`
```

What I'm trying to do is pass $link to my Livewire component (or Blade file if need be) so I can populate an input field like so:

```
`<div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('title', 'Title', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                                {!! Form::text('title', (isset($link) ? $link->filter('title')->text() : null), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Your catchy title']) !!}
                                @error('title')
                                <x-alert type="danger" :message="$message" />
                                @enderror
                            </div>`
```

I'm trying to avoid doing a complete page reload, hence Livewire to provide a better UX. Just cannot wrap my head around this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using events

```
public function scrape()
{
  $link = GoutteFacade::request('GET', $request->url);
  $this->emitTo('to-emit-component', 'sendLink',['data' => $link]);  
}
```

in the component to-emit-component listen the event

```
protected $listeners = [
   'sendLink'
];

public function sendLink($data)
{
   dd($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer will respond to the question but can give to others people hint to proceed otherwise.

Case: I created a mount method in Livewire file for getting query params. As a search issue, I wanted to populate inputs in other page submitting the query.
Query and Local are linked to livewire blade as model.

1. Livewire file
   public String $query = '';
   public String $local = '';

   public function mount(Request $request)
   {
   if ($request->input('searchQui') != '' && $request->input('searchOu') != '') {
   $this->query = $request->input('searchQui');
   $this->local = $request->input('searchOu');
   }
   }
2. Livewire Blade